# HTML, CSS - Prevent button from moving up when clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an accordion component and I came across a problem.

The problem is, the `.accordion_button` element moves up after being clicked on. I want to stay it to stay in the same spot.

How can I fix it? I tried to remove the padding of the `.accordion_button` element, and I changed the display type a few times but it still doesn't work.

```css
:root{
  --checked_color: #d3d3d3;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-size: 16px;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container{
  width: 400px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

.accordion_button{
  text-justify: justify;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 4em;
  background-color: #3e3ec3;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion_button > svg{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .accordion_button > svg{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  stroke: var(--checked_color);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .accordion_button{
  color: var(--checked_color); 
}

.accordion_content{
  display: none;
}

.accordion_content > h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .2em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .accordion_content{
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.accordion_button,.accordion_content {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.335);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accordion">
        <label for="accordion" class="accordion_button">
            <span>ITEM 1</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" />
              </svg>
        </label>
        <div class="accordion_content">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla harum maiores aperiam quo natus? Distinctio vitae officiis, maxime dolore nesciunt doloremque enim possimus unde nostrum eveniet! Ducimus unde nulla eos!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It moves, because you have the full body content *centered* on both axis. So if the *height* of the whole component increases, then that of course also changes the position within the body.

You can avoid that, by using `visibility` instead of `display` to hide/show the content. `display: none` removes an element completely - whereas `visibility: hidden` just *hides* it, but still keeps the space it requires reserved.

```css
:root{
  --checked_color: #d3d3d3;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-size: 16px;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container{
  width: 400px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

.accordion_button{
  text-justify: justify;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 4em;
  background-color: #3e3ec3;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion_button > svg{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .accordion_button > svg{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  stroke: var(--checked_color);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .accordion_button{
  color: var(--checked_color); 
}

.accordion_content{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.accordion_content > h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .2em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .accordion_content{
  visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.accordion_button,.accordion_content {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.335);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accordion">
        <label for="accordion" class="accordion_button">
            <span>ITEM 1</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" />
              </svg>
        </label>
        <div class="accordion_content">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla harum maiores aperiam quo natus? Distinctio vitae officiis, maxime dolore nesciunt doloremque enim possimus unde nostrum eveniet! Ducimus unde nulla eos!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```